# mysql select min price value exclude zero

Tags: mysql

I need to fetch the minimum price value and exclude zero values from database. Here is mysql query that is not working:

```
SELECT MIN(price) AS lowprice FROM price WHERE status = 1 AND price > 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `SELECT MIN(price) AS lowprice FROM price WHERE status = 1 AND price > 0`

Comment: tried but not worked

Comment: what do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: zero values are still coming in results

Comment: show me the proof.provide full fragment of your code. and sample of data

Comment: Some sample data would be appreciated, because that makes it easier for us to answer your question more accurately

Comment: @Alex thank you. query working. checked on wrong schema.

Comment: `SELECT price FROM price WHERE status = 1 AND price > 0 ORDER BY price LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this on my own database, and used:

```
SELECT MIN(price) AS lowprice 
FROM price 
WHERE status = 1 AND price > 0
```

This gave me all the values where status=1 and where price > 0.
So the only difference was `price > 0` instead of `price > 1`. But if you want to also exclude values of 1, then `price > 1` works too.

**Update:**

As [Juan Carlos Oropeza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3470178/juan-carlos-oropeza) said in comments, you don't need the `LIMIT 1`. I left it out of my code, but didn't mention this.

Comment: Also you dont need `LIMIT 1`  with `MIN()`

Answer (score 6):

In MySQL you can use the NULLIF function.

```
SELECT MIN(NULLIF(price, 0)) AS lowprice FROM price WHERE status=1
```

NULLIF will compare the price value with 0 and if it's true, it will return null.